Are crackpot ideas for attacking Bitcoin on-topic?
I have a question, but I'm not sure its topical for this site.
In brief, I think I've thought of a way to commit fraud against the whole bitcoin network with significantly less than 51% of hashing power at the attacker's disposal.
If I posted it, the only answers would either be "Yes. That would work. Well done, you've told the world how to destroy bitcoin." or more realisticly "If anyone tried that, it would fail because of an incorrect assumption you've made."
I suspect someone comes up with a crackpot idea like mine every week. Is the main site a place for crackpots like me?

Few crackpots I've ever met in real life have the presence of mind to consider where the most appropriate venue for their ideas is. Hence you've failed to convince me that the term applies at all.

Please do it. Security through obscurity doesn't work anyway.

In case anyone wondering, my crackpot idea needs to be developed a bit more before its ready to publish.

I think the main site is a perfect place for a question like this.
